# Is this result for entire functions with zeroes only at the origin... more basic than the Hadamard canonical product representation?

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity, hadamard-product

I just worked on a problem and was able to solve it pretty easily, using Hadamard's product representation.  But I wonder whether the solution that I compared my work to doesn't actually use the Hadamard factorization.

The question asks to determine the class of all functions $f$ such that

i) $f$ is analytic on the whole complex plane

ii) $f$ is zero if and only if z=0

iii) $|f(re^{i\theta}|\le e^{\delta r^3}$ for any $\delta >0$ and for all large $r$.

My work:

By part iii), we know that $f$ is a function of order m = 3, by definition.

By part i), $f$ is entire.

Then since $f$ is an entire function of finite order, it has a Hadamard canonical product representation:

$$f(z) = z^me^{g(z)} \prod \big(1- \frac {z}{z_n}\big)e^{\large \frac{z}{z_n}+...+\frac{1}{p}(\frac{z}{z_n})^p}$$

where we know that g(z) is a polynomial, since $f$ is of finite order.

Now by part ii) we know that $f(z)$ has no non-zero roots.  Then I think that the infinite product factor simply does not appear in the Hadamard factorization, and the class of functions is easily seen to be of the form

$$f(z) = z^me^{g(z)}$$

Where g(z) is a polynomial of degree at most d=3, in order to satisfy the growth condition of part iii).

So, my question is:  the solution simply says that $\large\frac {f}{z^m}$ is entire and never zero, and so it must have the form $e^{g(z)}$, where $g(z)$ is a polynomial of degree at most 3.  Is this solution saying the same thing as me?  Or is it saying something more basic?

...not that Hadamard's factorization is super difficult (although I remember there was essentially only one way to prove the factorization), but it is usually a topic that shows up much later in any complex variables book, and also what I have seen *early* in the textbooks is the rewriting of functions in the form of $e^g$, or $\frac{1}{f}$, etc to prove fundamental results -- e.g., maximum / minimum modulus principle stuff.

So, I wonder whether I have overlooked a basic result in solving this problem.  If so, I would love to be reminded of it :-)

Any comments are welcome.

Thanks,

Comment: I think the solution and you are both using facts that stem from common proofs. In either case, it's probably instructive to remember why the solution's proof is valid: any nonvanishing function $f(z)$ on a simply connected domain (in this case, the entire plane) always has a well-defined logarithm $g(z) = \log f(z)$ (indeed, infinitely many such that differ by multiples of $2\pi i$. In this case, the given bound says that $|g(z)| \le \delta|z|^3$ for all $|z|\ge1$ say; and any such function must be a polynomial of degree at most $3$ (which itself is a fact whose proof should be understood).

Comment: Thanks so much for your awesome comment, @GregMartin.  And I will now prove why g(z) must be a polynomial -- I've done it many times, using  Cauchy estimates, but I remember there was a clever way of proving it using the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra and possibly Liouville's Theorem.  I will try both again :-).

Comment: Hi @GregMartin, when you wrote $g(z) = log(f(z))$, the log is complex-log, so g(z) is of course...not entire.  How could I then show that g(z) is a polynomial of degree at most 3, using the standard Cauchy integral formula proof?  We need analyticity on and inside the circle of integration, and then let the circle (does not have to be a circle, apparently) grow to  infinity.  Without knowing that $g(z)$ is entire, we couldn't proceed in this way.  What do you think?  Thanks,

Comment: Actually, the whole point is my comment is that the hypotheses (non-vanishing of $f$ and simply-connectedness of the domain) do imply that $g$ is defined on the entire domain. In particular, if $f$ is a nonvanishing entire function, then $\log f$ *is* entire. (unlike $\log z$—but $z$ isn't a nonvanishing function)

Comment: Hi @GregMartin, I just worked on another problem that requires the use of $log(f)$ being entire (to arrive at $p(z)e^{g(z)}$ form),where $f$ is a non-vanishing entire function.  Last time you commented (on Dec 1st), I honestly just moved on to the next problem without actually understanding why $log f$ is entire, but I better do so now, I think.  Do you mind explaining it?  Just using the definition of complex logarithm with input $f$ isn't really insightful.  Is there something else obvious that I should realize that would make $log f$ entire, or is it a more technical proof?  Thanks so much,

Comment: It's good to really work at understanding the fundamentals! You could start here (and follow the footnote citation if you want further details): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm#Logarithms_of_holomorphic_functions

Comment: Hi @GregMartin, thanks for your response - I think I got it now :-)  if $f(z)$ is holomorphic and non-vanishing on some open, simply-connected set, then it has a well-defined complex logarithm $g:=log(f(z))$.  But by definition, the logarithm of $f(z)$, $g(z)$, is a number such that $e^{g} = f(z)$.  Now since $f(z)$ is holomorphic, then this forces the L.H.S. to be holomorphic, i.e., it forces $g(z) = log(f(z))$ to be holomorphic.

Comment: And by the same argument, if $f(z)$ is entire, then $g(z)$ must be entire.  And from the Wikipedia page, I picked up a little more info:  namely that $loge^{z}=z$ is not necessarily true; that the complex log inverts only a restriction of the complex exponential.  And, now I also know a little bit better why we need the simply-connectedness -- I think that this is to ensure that we can construct the logarithm in some open set with complex contour integration, and using the analyticity of the integrand on a simply connected, open set makes the integration path-independent.

Comment: The part of the Wiki page that is (and has always been) difficult to grasp is the discussion about Riemann surfaces. But I think for now, I will move on and hopefully at some in the future I will revisit the discussion about Riemann surfaces -- although every several years an exam question that asks for a description of a Riemann surface *does* come up, but it does not happen frequently :-)

Comment: Thanks so much for your time, @GregMartin -- please feel free to comment further, if you'd like.  Hope to hear from you soon.  Have a great night :-)